# Incode Platform Failing Integration Test

Tags: isis

I have created the quickstart app from the incode platform. Build is failing consistently.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Test set: domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObjectMenu_IntegTest$Create

### Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.294 sec - in domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObjectMenu_IntegTest$Create

### Test set: domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObjectMenu_IntegTest$ListAll

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.021 sec <<< FAILURE! - in domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObjectMenu_IntegTest$ListAll
happyCase(domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObjectMenu_IntegTest$ListAll)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService.persist(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObjectMenu_IntegTest$ListAll.happyCase(SimpleObjectMenu_IntegTest.java:43)

---

### Test set: domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$DataNucleusId

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.782 sec <<< FAILURE! - in domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$DataNucleusId
should_be_populated(domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$DataNucleusId)  Time elapsed: 0.034 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService.persist(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

---

### Test set: domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$DataNucleusVersionTimestamp

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE! - in domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$DataNucleusVersionTimestamp
should_be_populated(domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$DataNucleusVersionTimestamp)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService.persist(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

---

### Test set: domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$Name

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE! - in domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$Name
accessible(domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$Name)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService.persist(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

not_editable(domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$Name)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService.persist(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

---

### Test set: domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$Title

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE! - in domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$Title
interpolatesName(domainapp.modules.simple.integtests.tests.SimpleObject_IntegTest$Title)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
"tests.txt" 53L, 4999C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has also been raised and is answered on relevant github repo: https://github.com/incodehq/incode-platform/issues/14